# Snowflake SQL Procedure Error: Unexpected Issue with Variable Assignment

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating 2 variables and assign some value to it using case when then and then insert data into a final table , getting error while executing the proc.

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE "internal"."ivp_polaris_MonthEnd"(
"FUND" varchar(255),"LOADTYPE" VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
as
Begin

IF (FUND IS NULL OR FUND ='')
THEN
RETURN 'FUND is null.';
END IF;

FUND := CASE WHEN INSTR(FUND, '.file') > 0 THEN REPLACE(FUND, '.file', FUND) ELSE FUND END;
FUND := CASE WHEN FUND = 'SEGAM%' THEN 'SGAM%' ELSE FUND END;


IF (FUND = 'All') THEN
INSERT INTO "internal"."fund_dataload_status" ("FundName","created_on","LoadType")
SELECT  fund, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), :LoadType
FROM (
SELECT "Fund Name" AS fund
FROM "dimension"."fund_feeder_master_non_series"
UNION
SELECT "Feeder Master Name" AS fund
FROM "dimension"."fund_feeder_master_non_series"
) a
MINUS
SELECT "FundName" AS fund
FROM "internal"."fund_dataload_status" b
ELSE
INSERT INTO "internal"."fund_dataload_status" ("FundName","created_on","LoadType")
VALUES(:FUND, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), :LoadType);
END IF;

DELETE FROM "internal"."fund_dataload_status"
WHERE "FundName" IS NULL OR "FundName" = '';

RETURN 'Procedure completed.';
END;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's fixed now, error was due to a missing ; in if condition

Comment: @MohitSharma if it is fixed thanks to answer provided here, you should mark the response as an Answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing ; in your if condition

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE  "internal"."ivp_polaris_MonthEnd"(
"FUND" varchar(255),"LOADTYPE" VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
as
Begin

IF (FUND IS NULL OR FUND ='')
THEN
RETURN 'FUND is null.';
END IF;

FUND := CASE WHEN INSTR(FUND, '.file') > 0 THEN REPLACE(FUND, '.file', FUND) ELSE FUND END;
FUND := CASE WHEN FUND = 'SEGAM%' THEN 'SGAM%' ELSE FUND END;



IF (:FUND = 'All') THEN
    INSERT INTO "internal"."fund_dataload_status" ("FundName","created_on","LoadType")
    SELECT  fund, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), :LoadType
    FROM (
        SELECT "Fund Name" AS fund
        FROM "dimension"."fund_feeder_master_non_series"
        UNION
        SELECT "Feeder Master Name" AS fund
        FROM "dimension"."fund_feeder_master_non_series"
    ) a
    MINUS
    SELECT "FundName" AS fund
    FROM "internal"."fund_dataload_status" b;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO "internal"."fund_dataload_status" ("FundName","created_on","LoadType")
    VALUES(:FUND, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), :LoadType);
END IF;

DELETE FROM "internal"."fund_dataload_status"
WHERE "FundName" IS NULL OR "FundName" = '';



RETURN 'Procedure completed.';
END;
```

Comment: Yes , correct ; was missing. Thanks